# Blocking Queue elements are not visible to other thread sometimes causing no elements to retrieve

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, blocking

I am using `LinkedBlokingQueue` and it is shared between 2 threads. From the 1st thread constructor I have passed `Queue` object to 2nd thread.

I use `likedBlockingQueue.put` in 1st thread.

Second thread uses `likedBlockingQueue.size()>0` and `likedBlockingQueue.peek()` to get the element.

The issue is in 1 of my environment sometimes the second thread is giving empty, though I can see the first thread is at blocking call at put (as I have initialized queue size as 1). This issue is not happening always but only replicating sometimes. Couldn't able to understand what causes this issue as per the java documents this Queue seems to be thread safe. Could anyone share any points on this?

I tried replicating this but only happens few times, other times I could able to get the element from the Queue.

**1 Thread**:

```
private final Queue<T> linkedQ = new LinkedBlokingQueue(1);
linkedQ.put(element);
```

**2 Thread**:

```
while(condition)
{
    if(this.linkedQ.size>0)
    {
        Object a = this.linkedQ.peek();
        linkedQ.remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

No error, when I debug when this issue happened, the Q in the second thread showed empty.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should be using neither `size()` nor `peek()` nor `remove()`. The [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) is a queue that blocks (hence the name). Both `size()` and `peek()` are non-blocking (well, technically they block for a second, but they don't act in a producer-consumer fashion).

You want an operation that tells the current thread "Wait here until an element appears on the queue". Looking at the API, for `peek()` it reads

> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

Returning null if the queue is empty explains that no waiting is performed. The operation you're looking for is `take()`.

> public E take()
>
> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.

Your usage here would then be:

```
while(condition) {
    Object a = linkedQ.take(); // leaving out the interrupted exception for brevities sake
}
```

Comment: Hi jhon thanks for the reply I got your point, but my doubt is in this case as the Queue is thread safe it always will see whenever the other thread puts the element into Q, will get the size more than 0, so it will remove from the Q. This is what i am anticipating but not happening like this, thats what i am not able to understand

Comment: First, you should never call the `size` method. Upon first invoking `take()` it's very likely the queue will be empty, but the thread will suspend until another thread `put()`s. There is thread communication going on (the putting thread wakes up the taking thread).

Comment: But according to the java doc, size will be returning the elements in the Q, so its not having any issue right?

Comment: The purpose of the BlockingQueue is to have a thread wait until the queue has an element. Most of the time the queue will be empty. `so its not having any issue right?` No issue what-so-ever. You need not worry about the size of the queue if you want to wait/block for an element to exist. And based on your example, it looks like you should be waiting for an element to be on the queue

Comment: Yeah, i have tried same, but original issue is that from the second thread sometimes its not able to get the element, I have taken thread dumps and in first thread object is put into Q but from second thread it never retrieved thread is just stuck at take condition

Comment: Are you sure that it wasn't already processed? There are two reasonable things to conclude, (1) When you looked at the thread dump, the element you had put in was processed already and the thread is waiting for another element. (2) You are referencing a different queue. I would do two things - first, print some logging after the element is taken from the queue (using `take()`) and print the queue's `System.identityHash` after constructing and prior to `take()` to make sure they are the same.